# Why newline character in a file created by Python stops the cycle in bash script reading this file?

Tags: python, bash

Python script creates a file as follows

```
...
f.write(title)
f.write("\n")
f.write(body)
...
```

Bash script reads a file line by line as follows

```
...
while read line
do
  ...
done < $1
...
```

The while cycle runs only once.

I have already narrowed the place where is the cause.

When I edit the file, and append one character to the first line, it works (the while cycle runs twice).

When I delete the last character of the first line, it works (the while cycle runs twice). Though the file looks like the original file now.

What is the cause?

Comment: @Jahid File content is not important. The cause is in the `f.write("\n")` and when you append one character to the end it works and when you delete that character it still works.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why should `while` loop twice?

Comment: @DisplayName Because there are two lines in the file.

Comment: Then it is *one* loop that does *two* things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line in your file doesn't end with a newline, so `read` thinks it has reached the end-of-file and causes the `while` loop to exit. When you edit the file your editor fixes the last line silently adding the missing newline, and your `read` loop works like expected.

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting that `read` needs newline at the end of the file.

Comment: I don't think it's just `read`. Most of the unix tools expect text files to be terminated by a newline.